# Search algorithms

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

In javascript, I want to have a function with this declaration:
`function sumOfTwoItemExist(arr:number[],total:number)=>boolean`

the first parameter would be an array of numbers and the 2nd would be a number, now I want to return true if the sum of any pair of numbers in the passed array is equal to the passed number.
for example: 
`sumOfTwoItemExist([1,2,3,4],5) => true //1+4=5`
`sumOfTwoItemExist([1,2,3,4],8)=> false`

what is the best and most optimized way to implement this array?
simply I tried to implement the function with a tow loop like this:

```js
function sumOfTwoItemExist(arr,total) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
      if (arr[i] + arr[j] === total) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(sumOfTwoItemExist([1, 2, 3, 4], 5)) // => true 1+4=5 
console.log(sumOfTwoItemExist([1, 2, 3, 4], 8)) // false
```

but I'm not sure it's the most optimized way.
please share your suggestions.

Comment: I want your solution to this problem. if it's not clear say me to explain it again.

Comment: [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: @mplungjan Any question requesting alternate solutions is off-topic on code review. Code review is for improving the authors coding ability, not alternate solutions.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to the previous answer is to create a mapping object which holds every number and their indexes from the array as key value pairs.

Now with each iteration we check if the difference between the sum and the current number exists in the map, if it does that means that we have found our pair and we can return true, else return false.

Here is the implementation:

```js
const sumOfTwoItemExist = function(nums, target) {
  const map = {}

  for (let i = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++) {
    const temp = target - nums[i]
    if (typeof map[temp] !== 'undefined') {
      return true;
    } else {
      map[nums[i]] = i
    }
  }
  return false
}

console.log(sumOfTwoItemExist([1, 2, 3, 4], 5)) // => true 1+4=5 
console.log(sumOfTwoItemExist([1, 2, 3, 4], 8)) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `2-pointer` algorithm here:

> If array is already sorted then you can skip sorting, this algo takes O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity.
>
> else it O(n log n) if it is not sorted

```js
function sumOfTowItemExist(arr: number[], total: number): boolean {
  const sortArr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let leftPtr = 0,
    rightPtr = sortArr.length - 1;

  while (leftPtr < rightPtr) {
    let sum = sortArr[leftPtr] + sortArr[rightPtr];
    if (sum === total) return true;
    if (sum < total) leftPtr++;
    else rightPtr++;
  }

  return false;
}


const result = sumOfTowItemExist([1, 2, 3, 4], 5) // => true //1+4=5 

console.log(result);
```

Comment: please share your idea about this problem too. if it's possible. I want to pass the third parameter to the function named N and the function should return true if the sum of N elements of the array is equal to the total parameter. which algorithm do you think would be the most optimized one? thanks.